# How to transfer binary files from a C#/websocket server to the client?

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a tcp server where I have implemented a websocket server to communicate with the client, and it works great.

I have a requirement to send files from server to my client, I know I can open the file and send the data to the browser and I will receive it in `onmessage` event of `websocket`, but I don\t know how to create a file on client side and how can I write the received data to the file.

It seems very simple thing but I don't know how to do it ?

Any help with some sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Suppose your server sends *malware* to the client. Whouldn't it be a security bug? So I don't think an automated process should work without user's consent

Comment: @L.B This is created for internal use so no problem about security issues.

Comment: ShrShr, Just brain storming. Internal or not, whould some tools(such as browser) allow you to do this? (Would you allow it if you were the the writer of the browser)

Comment: @L.B But how can we then download files from internet, those are also sent by some server ?

Comment: Do you see the difference between a) *pulling(downloading) file from server* b) *server pushes some files to you without you knowing it* . If not, forget my comments.

Comment: @L.B No, we know what we ask, I mean we ask for some file by making a request, I want to do the same, sending req for some file from my client and server should push that file to my client and I should be able to save that to my disk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54942/discussion-between-shrshr-and-l-b).